# How to replace "{* foo *}" with nothing?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to replace all text what start with "{*" and end with "*}" including those "{*" and "*}". Text between them may be anything. =(
I guess I need to use regex's there.

Let's imagine that $this->output is string that I want to replace. So I got this far... It don't work by the way. =(

```
$this->output = preg_replace( '/{*(.*)*}/', $this->output, $this->output );
```

Comment: Your replacement and subject parameters ... are the same?

Comment: Your question title and content don't match. Are you replacing `{* foo *}` or `{ foo }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `*`:

```
'/{\*(.*)\*}/'
```

Otherwise `*` is interpreted as [quantifier](http://php.net/regexp.reference.repetition). Furthermore, to have `.*` not to match as much as possible, make the `*` quantifier reluctant:

```
'/{\*(.*?)\*}/'
```

Comment: Are curly braces treated literally if not used as quantifiers? (I remember once asking you about square braces too...)

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. If `{…}` is not a valid quantifier it is interpreted as literal: “An opening curly bracket that appears in a position  where a quantifier is not allowed, or one that does not match the syntax of a quantifier, is taken as a literal character.”

Comment: I think this will fail on "{*foo*}bar*}" by matching the full string (it does so in Python at least), when it's more likely OP wants to match "{*foo*}". My answer fixes this.

Comment: @marcog: It works for me: `re.match(r"{\*(.*?)\*}", "{*foo*}bar*}").group(0) == "{*foo*}"` is true.

Comment: @Gumbo My bad. I just read your first regex and missed your latter.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the question text which asks to match `{foo}`, `{[^}]*}` which will match anything in `{` / `}`'s.

Going by the subject which asks to match `{*foo*}`, `{\*.*?\*}` which will match anything in `{*` / `*}`'s. To match only `{*foo*}` in `{* foo {*foo*}`, use `{\*((?!{\*).)*?\*}`.

Comment: Note that this will match `{*{*foo*}` in something like `{*{*foo*}*}`.

Comment: @Gumbo Edited in a fix for this, although I'm unsure if PHP supports negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is slightly unclear so I'll address both cases.

To replace the foo in {*foo*} use the regex:

```
/{\*([^}])*\*}/
```

To replace the *foo* in {*foo*} use the regex:

```
/{([^}])*}/
```